# MongoDb remove object elements from an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have removed the contents of an element in an array but how can I remove it entirely so the index position disappears. Right now,  the index position it was sitting at has the value of `null`.

[image]

How can I remove these null indexes entirely because my html iterates over the array so the index position with `null` values are still being processed. This is my current update method. I intend to completely remove the element. I query the object by matching the object id.

click event: docId = this.docId

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId, 'profile.experiences.docId': docId}, {$unset: {'profile.experiences.$': docId}});
```

The objects are created in the method as follows:

```
var expDoc = {
        contents: ' ',
        rank: ' ',
        docId: new Mongo.ObjectID()
    };
    Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId}, {$addToSet: {'profile.experiences': expDoc}});
```

Comment: When you're removing the items from array, can't you get rid of that `null`. Are you using `$pull` modifier?

Comment: I'm using the unset. Each element is an array. I am attempting to completely remove the element, but so far, I am removing the everything inside the element only.Which is why the index position states null. However, I want to completely get rid of the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) instead of [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset).

Your update query should look like this:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$pull: {'profile.experiences': {docId: docId}}});
```

The `$pull` performs a search of the given array so you don't have to search for documents which match both the `_id` **and** the `profile.experiences.docId` - you just need to find the `_id`.

Comment: This works does works. My syntax was off in the call.